# Why do I need to generalize/parameterize an integral sometimes to get a closed form result?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, evaluation, symbolic, special-functions, expression-manipulation

```
Integrate[x^(1/3) AiryAi[x], {x, 0, ∞}]
(* Integrate[x^(1/3) AiryAi[x], {x, 0, ∞}] *)

Integrate[x^a AiryAi[x], {x, 0, ∞}] /. a -> 1/3
(* Gamma[1/3]/(3^(1/9) Gamma[1/9]) *)
```

- Why do I need to generalize/parameterize an integral sometimes to get a closed form result? Should cases like this be considered as bugs?
- How can I tell what kinds of generalization may help in a particular case? Do you know any other tricks besides replacing a constant with a parameter?

Comment: What  version of `Mathematica` are you using?  In `ver.8` I get the first integral unevaluated and this warning `Integrate::idiv: Integral of x^(1/3) AiryAi[x] does not converge on {0, ∞}. >>`. But in `ver.9` the first integral evaluates to this `(2^(4/9) Sqrt[Pi] Gamma[13/18] Sin[Pi/18] + 
 Cos[Pi/18] Gamma[4/9] Gamma[7/
   9] (Cos[Pi/9] + Sqrt[3] Sin[Pi/9]))/(2 3^(7/9) Pi)`. This is numerically equal to the second integral. The second one behaves as you claim.

Comment: In 11.1 both return results, which agree in numerical value, but have very different forms.